# HTTP server GET command

Tags: java, sockets

I have created a server and I am expected to expand it so it understands only the specified HTTP GET commands which will be send from browser and will send the response to the get commands; it does not have to be anything special and must be done on java 1.6.

I am unsure how to implement this or how to even send the GET command.  **My question is:** how do I send and read the GET command and how to respond to I using sockets, no runtimes.

```
 package server;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

import blogs.Logs;
import blogs.ServerMessages;

import logins.StreamUP;

public class TwipperServer implements Runnable {
Socket csocket;

TwipperServer(Socket csocket) {
    this.csocket = csocket;
}

Logs serverLogs = new Logs();
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
boolean loginBool = false;
String tempUser = null;
String tempPass = null;
StreamUP strm = new StreamUP();
boolean userLogout = false;
String strMessage = "Enter Username";
List<ServerMessages> postedMessages = new ArrayList<ServerMessages>();

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
    while (true) {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        new Thread(new TwipperServer(clientSocket)).start();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void chooseMethod(int num) throws IOException {
    String inputLine;

    switch (num) {
    case 1:// add status
        out.println("Enter status");
        inputLine = in.readLine();
        serverLogs.addMessage(tempUser, new Date(), inputLine);
        serverLogs.updateLogs();
        break;
    case 2:// remove status by specific date and hour
        int year,
        month,
        date,
        hrs,
        min = 0;
        out.println("Enter year");
        year = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        out.println("Enter month");
        month = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        out.println("Enter day");
        date = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        out.println("Enter hour");
        hrs = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        Date de = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, date, hrs, min);
        List<ServerMessages> removeLogs = new ArrayList<ServerMessages>();

        for (ServerMessages temp : serverLogs.messageLogs) {
            if (temp.getUser().equals(tempUser)) {
                if (temp.getDate().getYear() == de.getYear()
                        && temp.getDate().getMonth() == de.getMonth()
                        && temp.getDate().getDay() == de.getDay()) {
                    int hour = de.getHours();
                    int compare = temp.getDate().getHours();
                    if (compare == hour)
                        removeLogs.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        serverLogs.messageLogs.removeAll(removeLogs);
        serverLogs.updateLogs();
        break;
    case 3:// show messages containing specific hashtag
        String hashTag;
        out.println("Enter hashtag you wish to search");
        hashTag = in.readLine();

        for (ServerMessages temp : serverLogs.messageLogs) {
            temp.getHash(hashTag);
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        for (ServerMessages n : serverLogs.messageLogs) {
            System.out.println(n.getData());
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                csocket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        int inputCom;

        while (userLogout == false) {
            while (loginBool == false) {// how to send html password request
                out.println(strMessage);// for username and password
                tempUser = in.readLine();
                out.println("Enter password: ");
                tempPass = in.readLine();
                loginBool = strm.validity(tempUser, tempPass);
                strMessage = "Incorrect username or password. Please try again. Enter Username: ";
            }// end while loop for login check
            strMessage = "Press 1 to add message";
            out.println(strMessage);
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            inputCom = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);

            try {
                chooseMethod(inputCom);// what to do
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// end while loop for userlogout
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out
                .println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                        + 9999 + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.close();
        try {
            csocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you already have a server that that understands HTTP protocol, you can try [HTTP Apache Client](http://hc.apache.org/) to write your client. Or use the `java.net.URLConnection` class. You might want to read about REST, I think would help you building your application. PS: My comment is just addition to user1676075 answer. Also, you can try with your browser :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a page with a pretty good summary of the HTTP protocol (though feel free to search and find others): http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/.
Basically, http is just sending a stream of text to a socket and receiving a response. The request starts with "GET  "  (e.g. "GET /some/path HTTP/1.0"). There may or may not be additional headers and data. The response is similar "  ", e.g. "HTTP/1.0 200 OK", followed by headers and data (including content).

It's an achievable project because HTTP is a simple protocol of request/response.

If you're really asking about how to read/write from sockets, it's a simple read from socket (javadoc for the API) until you reach the end of the request, then sending the response.